# I have sitemap.xml but many SEO audit websites say I don't have...what is the fix?

Tags: seo, sitemap, robots.txt

I have geenrated sitemap.xml and I have installed it on my website public-folders so my website www.example.com/sitemap.xml is working. However I have used several SEO audit tools like Woorank and SEO power suite, they all say sitemap.xml is not found, even I have included it in the robots.txt file

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
User-agent: *
Disallow: /directory-x
Disallow: /directory-y
```

and still the same issue. Did I miss anything in placing my sitemap.xml?

Comment: can you access to sitemap.xml in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /directory-x
Disallow: /directory-y
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
Host: www.example.com
```

Comment: I see only the host is added. Do you think this will fix the issue?.

Comment: And the "sitemap" goes after "user-agent"

Comment: you have nailed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your sitemap properly with a browser, then you are fine. If you want confirmation by a 3rd party, register your website at [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) and submit your sitemap there. If there is any issue (even a `robot.txt` issue), Google will let you know.

Comment: So I should not trust those 3rd party SEO audit sites like Woorank or checksiteseo.com?

Comment: Trust what GSC says before other websites. GSC may detect something you did not spot yourself yet. If it does not spot anything, forget about the other websites...

Comment: I have GSC account where should I go to make an audit for my website inside GSC?

Comment: Go to Crawl > Sitemaps, there is a button to add and test sitemaps.